# PHP's preg_match() returns (.*?) value only

Tags: php, preg-match

I am struggling to get [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to return only the image URL and not the entire matched string. Do I need to use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) after or is that getting hacky?

Possibly, would a different syntax get me what I need?

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://mysite.co.uk');
preg_match_all("'<div id=\"my-div\"><img src=\"(.*?)\" /></div>'", $source, $match);
echo $match[0][0];
```

Comment: [The pony he comes....](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use echo `$match[0][0]` you will have all the text.

```html
<div id="my-div"><img src="blabla bla" /></div>
```

If you write `$match[1][0]` instead, you will get your subpattern match:

```
blabla bla
```

Comment: I believe it should be `$match[1][0]`

Comment: $match[1][0]; got me what I needed. Array issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the first instance, you don't need to use `preg_match_all()`:

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://mysite.co.uk');
if (preg_match('#<div id="my-div"><img src="(.*?)" /></div>#', $source, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
} else {
    // no match found
}
```

Note that this regex will not match across multiple lines.

If you need *all* matches, then you were on the right track, but you were using index `0` instead of `1`, so:

```
preg_match_all(..., $match);
foreach ($match as $m) {
    echo $m[1]; // Use 1 here instead of 0; 1 is the first capture group, where 0 is the entire matched string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `preg_match_all` always returns the fully matched string as the first item (using the ordering type `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`).

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`:

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern
> matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first
> parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

If you're looking for the value of a capturing group, check for a value at index 1 and then use the capturing group reference as a subattribute.

E.g., capturing group 1 would be: `$matches[1][0]`

To change this behavior you can pass a constant to as the third argument, such as `PREG_SET_ORDER`, which "Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of first set of matches, $matches[1] is an array of second set of matches, and so on."